# Can be used pwa as a desktop rwd website simultaneously?

Tags: responsive-design, progressive-web-apps

I want to create a web application. Before knowing about pwa, i wanna to create my wep app with rwd(responsive web design) that implements by react. 
I don't want to have two seperated url and site for pwa and desktop. What could i do? Can i use serviceworker and manifest in root of my rwd design ? When users go to url in mobile, they see pwa and in desktop they see rwd. Just with one url. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes service workers and manifest will help you accomplish this. The pwa will be from the Responsive Web Design, meaning you Progressive Web App is linked to the rwd.
See explanation:  https://www.optasy.com/blog/3-essential-steps-convert-your-website-progressive-web-app